# Import contact from social networka and emails in .net

Tags: c#, .net, social-networking

I need import contact from Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook and maybe Facebook. I want to use API foreach service, becouse I do not want to have user password for these seervice and I want contact name, email, phone and photo so I cannot use pop3. I s there some nuget package or open source which I can use or I muset write foreach service myself?

Comment: Have you researched any of the packages yet? Googled as to how to interface with the difference APIs and how different places do what with multi API interfacing?

Answer (score -1):

Sure, as far as I know you can try the followings in the nuget package console

```
Install-Package GoogleOpenAuthV2
Install-Package FacebookLoginAPI
Install-Package MsLiveAuthCore
Install-Package TwitterBootStrapperAuthModule
Install-Package YahooIsStillAround
Install-Package GenericSocialMediaAuthSvc
```

Comment: These seem like valid packages that would answer OPs question, why the downvote?

Comment: If even one of them would exist.